# NHibernate Current Version

Tags: nhibernate

What is the current "production ready" version of NHibernate? I get conflicting answers on the hibernate site vs some other posts. Is it 2 or 2.1?? If it's 2.1 where do I get that binary?

Comment: forget about hibernate.org for NHibernate. just go to nhforge.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.1
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/

Answer (score 3):

The latest production version of NHibernate is 2.1. However there was a large change in 2.1 that is probably preventing people from making the jump right away. Maybe that is why you are getting conflicting answers.

- You can always get the latest version from [nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/)
- Details about the removal of the [proxy framework here](http://nhibernate.info/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.html)
- Don't forget to grab yourself a copy of [NHibernate Linq](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx) while you are at it

Answer (score 0):

[NHibernate-2.1.0.GA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/NHibernate/2.1.0.GA/NHibernate-2.1.0.GA-bin.zip/download)